# Use two GetXmlHttpObject results

Tags: javascript, response, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to add functionality to a small php/js I've built, but I can't make it work.
In general, i make two GETS of two different URL, and I need to use the reply of this URL in two different boxes.
I'v tried: seperate var port_name; and them just equals / to call $port_name or port_name.

Relevant part of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showPortName()
{
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlHttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
  return;
  }
var oob=document.getElementById("oob_name").value;
var port=document.getElementById("port").value;
var url="oob_get_port_name.php";
var url2="oob_get_location.php";
url=url+"?oob="+oob+"&port="+port;
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlHttp.send(null);
var port_name=xmlHttp.responseText.value;
url2=url2+"?oob="+oob+"&port="+port;
xmlHttp.open("GET",url2,true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
        {
        document.getElementById("device_name").value=$port_name;
        document.getElementById("device_location").value=xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
var xmlHttp=null;
try
  {
  // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
catch (e)
  {
  // Internet Explorer
  try
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
  catch (e)
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  }
return xmlHttp;
} 

</script>
```

Comment: You can't return from an asynchronous function, and what's with all the try/catch stuff ?

Comment: I've treid to change the xmlHttp.open("GET",url2,true) --> to false. same.

Comment: For the second request, you should use a new `xmlHttp2=GetXmlHttpObject()`

Comment: I can't mark you comment as "answer" but it makes sense and even working ! :) Thanks!!!